# How do I rebind jquery calls after ajax load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Okay so I use a masonry script for arranging images in a grid, I placed it in a function arange_images() in an external script.

In my main script i call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    arange_images();      //<- Works lovely
});
```

Then i decide to load some other images with ajax. After that, my images stop being arranged.

```
function get_img(section_id) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: './db/get_img.php',
    data: {
        section_id: section_id
    },
    success: function (data) {

        var data_parsed = JSON.parse(data);
        var images = '<div class="grid-sizer"></div><div class="gutter-sizer"></div>';

        $.each(data_parsed, function (i, picture) {
            images += '<div class="member">';
            images += '    <img src="img/pictures/' + picture.path + '" alt="' + picture.alt + '"/>';
            images += '</div>';
        });

        $('.grid').html(images);

        arange_images();       //<- Does not work

    }

 });
}





$('.section_selector').click(function () {
        get_img($(this).attr('data-section_id'));
        arange_images();           //<- Does not work either
    });
```

Searching similar errors did not help me.
Most of the problems with jquery after ajax are .click replaced with .on('click').
I read that I need to rebind jquery calls, but I don't really understand how to do it in this situation.

Comment: What does `arange_images();` do?

Comment: @admcfajn Here is the script https://masonry.desandro.com/

 
It adds padding values to all images (directly inside their img tag) in a certain div to create mosaic look.

Comment: @admcfajn As the script is over a thousand lines of compressed code I can only tell you in short.

It scans the .grid which contains images (that i change with ajax) and inserts position attributes inside html img tags.

Answer (score 2):

Your `.click()` handler will only bind elements that exist within the DOM at the time the document is ready.  Since you need to bind to the elements after the ajax call, use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

[Keep Calm and Call .on](https://www.keepcalm-o-matic.co.uk/p/keep-calm-and-call-on-108/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.section_selector'), function () {
    get_img($(this).attr('data-section_id'));
});
```

Comment: Tried it. Does not help. .section_selector always exists and isn't changed by ajax. You have two extra parentheses after ._section_selector, right?

Comment: @UC3D Then the problem is likely in your `arange_images()` function.  Can you post that code as well?

Comment: Sure,  here it is    https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4.2.1/dist/masonry.pkgd.js. 

I just put it all in arange_images(). It works well on page load or button click. For example if i fire it with a click of a button it works, then if i load some other images and fire it again it doesnt. If I don't fire it, load some images, then fire it,  it works and If i try to load images for second time and then fire it again, it doesn't.